# Input String was not in a correct format from empty string

Tags: c#

I have the following code which create an object from array of string.

```
struct Item
    {
        public Int32 ItemID { get; }
        public String ItemText { get; }
        public Int32 CategoryID { get;}
        public Int32 GroupID { get;}
        public String LargePictureName { get; }

        public Item(string[] menuItem)
        {
            DateTime minDateTime = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value;

            ItemID = String.IsNullOrEmpty(menuItem[0]) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(menuItem[0]);
            ItemText = menuItem[1];
            CategoryID = String.IsNullOrEmpty(menuItem[2]) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(menuItem[2]);
            GroupID = String.IsNullOrEmpty(menuItem[3]) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(menuItem[3]);
            LargePictureName = menuItem[4];
```

But when I run this code I got an Exception "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'" from this line 
LargePictureName = menuItem[4];
This is stack trace

Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/UnhandledUnhandled exceptionAMenuImportTool.exeSystem.FormatException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089Input string was not in a correct format.   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer&amp; number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
   ...
I confused because there is no conversion on that line.
I tried debug it and found that menuItem[4] is empty string. I tried change this line to 
LargePictureName = "1";
but I still got the same exception. I just don't understand there is no conversion in this line but why I got an exception from conversion to Int32. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I wonder if you saw the question yours is a duplicate of, since your code is similar to the accepted answer, but you missed the part of the answer that said _"and throw an exception on poorly formatted input"_?

Comment: It turned out that I really have problem with conversion. But it's not from this line. My original code is longer and has similar conversion as above code that I pasted. Visual Studio tried to point me to this line which confused me for an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is quite simple, however it's not on the line you think it is, and likely here, or before.

```
GroupID = String.IsNullOrEmpty(menuItem[3]) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(menuItem[3])
```

Basically one of your menuItems is not an actual number.

If this is user input, it's always better to use [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) to validate it before hand instead of just throwing on invalid input.

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
> integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation
> succeeded.

A slightly more robust way of doing this might be

```
int res = 0;
ItemID = int.TryParse(menuItem[0], out res ) ? res : 0;
ItemText = menuItem[1];
CategoryID = int.TryParse(menuItem[2], out res ) ? res : 0;
GroupID = int.TryParse(menuItem[3], out res ) ? res : 0;
```

<sub>***Note** : if you are not expecting null or a numeric value, you should investigate why this is failing thoroughly first*</sub>

---

**Additional Resources**

[Convert.ToInt32(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_Single_)

> Converts the specified string representation of a number to an
> equivalent 32-bit signed integer.
>
> **Exceptions**
>
> `FormatException`
>
> value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of
> digits (0 through 9).